# Can a form tag enclose a body tag?

Tags: html, forms

Today I came accross some code which had a form tag before the body tag began. I mean, the form tag enclosed the body tag. Is this possible? If it is then where is it helpfull?

```
<form  action="someaction.jsp" method="post">
 <body>
  ...
 </body>
</form>
```

Comment: *"Is it possible?"* Yes, it is possible, you have seen it yourself. But this is broken layout. Browser will try to fix it, but you should not do it of course.

Comment: Can you show us the code?

Comment: why you need to do this...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By looking up the `W3C Recommendations` [Form](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-form-element) elements description, it clearly shows that you better not use that way.

You can use the `Form` element in:

> Contexts in which this element can be used: Where flow content is
>   expected.

Where [Flow content](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#flow-content-1) is described as:

> Most elements that are used in the body of documents and applications
>   are categorized as **flow content**.

So by not following these recommendations, any HTML validators will also report you errors, since the forms opening closing tags are not found in side the body definition. Which is perfectly valid since:

> Tag omission in text/html: **Neither tag is omissible.**

Answer (score 2):

Browser follows a forgiving approach but when I use it against the validator, it just throws up these errors. It is always good to follow the standards or browsers get confused.

[image: Errors in W3C Validator]

Answer (score 1):

Browsers are generally very forgiving when it comes to mistakes in the HTML structure, so it is possible and the form may still work, but it's still improperly coded HTML and it won't be helpful for anything in particular.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible; the browser will mitigate it.

But it's unproper HTML syntax and I can't think of any cases where it might be helpful. The HTML body it just what it says on the label - a global page body container.