# Flask loop through POST Requests with input data

Tags: python, html, json, post, flask

So I have created code that fetches json data from a schedule and prints the key value pairs with for loops on a flask template. The values from the pairs are in a text field and you should be able to update the values when submitting. The problem is I do not get how to be able to loop through every lecture from the schedule, I just manage to do it to the first one.

Here is my form

```
<form method="POST">
    <body>
    <h1>Uppdatera lektion</h1>
        {%for dict_item in update%}
        <br>
            {%for key, value in dict_item.items()%}
                <br>
                    <b>{{key}}</b>
                    <input type="text" name="values" value="{{value}}"/>
                </br>
            {%endfor%}
        </br>
        {%endfor%}
    <input type=submit value=Registrera>
    </body>
</form>
```

Here is my post method

```
if request.method == "POST":
    input_values = request.form.getlist("values")

    url = "https://ltu.instructure.com/api/v1/calendar_events.json"

    payload = {
        'calendar_event[context_code]': "MY_USER",
        'calendar_event[title]': input_values[0],
        'calendar_event[start_at]': input_values[1]+"T"+input_values[2]+"Z",
        'calendar_event[end_at]': input_values[3]+"T"+input_values[4]+"Z",
        'calendar_event[description]': input_values[5]
        }

    headers = {
        'Authorization': "MY_TOKEN",
        'cache-control': "no-cache",
        'Postman-Token': "e0bc1a1c-5baf-47f8-a2ce-62d476040e73"
        }

    r = requests.post(url, data=payload, headers=headers)

    print(r.text)
return "Uppdateringen lyckades!"
```

Here is how the lecture format with keys and values looks like on the browser

https://i.stack.imgur.com/OiNo0.jpg

So yeah, I need some advice here on how to move on and be able to update all the lectures not just the first one. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should take a look to basic HTML format. A `body` tag inside a `form`, isn't good. Check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30976969/can-a-form-tag-enclose-a-body-tag
Also, use the same name for multiple input fields doesn't look great either since each implementation parse this differently.

Comment: @spaniard Yeah okey thanks, but do you have any suggestions on my problem?

Comment: I posted an answer with several suggestions @user10712526, I hope they help.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should add `[]`to values in your form to be multivalued as follows:

```
<input type="text" name="values[]" value="{{value}}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

As I told you in my comment, you should not be using the same attribute `name` for several `input` fields. That complicates everything, first because each implementation parses it differently (there is no standard), second and more important, it makes your work very very difficult (I would say impossible, but there might be something I miss).

How do you differ between which `input_value` belong to `title` and which to `description`? I see in your code you use the ordering, but I am not sure the order is kept. Also, do you know the keys of `dict_items

I would recommend you use something like this:

```
{% for index, dict_item in enumerate(update) %}
<br>
    <input type="hidden" name="item_count" value="{{ len(update) }}"/>
    {% for key, value in dict_item.items() %}
        <br>
            <b>{{key}}</b>
            <input type="text" name="{{key + index}}" value="{{value}}"/>
        </br>
    {% endfor %}
</br>
{% endfor %}
```

and then get the them as:

```
item_count = request.form['item_count']

for i in range(item_count):

    # key_0, key_1, key_2, etc... should be replace for the corresponding keys of dict_item 
    # that you use for build your form.
    # Dict are unordered, I used the numbers to reflect the previous order you were using.
    payload = {
        'calendar_event[context_code]': "MY_USER",
        'calendar_event[title]': input_values[key_0 + i],
        'calendar_event[start_at]': input_values[key_1 + i]+"T"+input_values[key_2 + i]+"Z",
        'calendar_event[end_at]': input_values[key_3 + i]+"T"+input_values[key_4 + i]+"Z",
        'calendar_event[description]': input_values[key_5 + i]
    }

    # Do with payload whatever you want to do.
```

Answer (score 0):

@spaniard unfortunately, I am not able to use python methods in my flask template, such as enumerate and len. I messed around a bit and came up with this:

```
{%for dict_item in update%}
    <br>
        {%for key, value in dict_item.items()%}
            <br>
                <b>{{key}}</b><input type="hidden" name="keys" value="{{key}}" />
                <input type="text" name="values" value="{{value}}"/>
            </br>
        {%endfor%}
    </br>
{%endfor%}
```

What I did in my python code, fetched the two list with new values for the keys and made a new list with them.

`input_values = request.form.getlist("values")
 item_count = request.form.getlist("keys")
 new_list = list(zip(item_count, input_values))`

Not really sure how to move on though, any suggestions?